# Save switch into a variable or call the switch later on

Tags: php, forms, switch-statement

I have a foreach loop which prints the numbers from 1-12, every number is a reference to a question and answer. 
The switch statement gets the information and prints the summary.

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {


    $groupSplit = str_split($name, 5);
//  print_r("Group Num: " . $groupSplit[1] . "<br/>");

    $optSplit = str_split($value, 3); // splits opt and the num x 
//  print_r("Option Num " . $optSplit[1] . "<br/>");



switch ($groupSplit[1]) {
    case 1:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group1 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1] . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button><button>Confirm and Send</button>") ;
        break;
    case 2:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group2 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group3 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>" ;
        break;
    case 4:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group4 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 5:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group5 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 6:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group6 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 7:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group7 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 8:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group8 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 9:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group9 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 10:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group10 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]). "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>" ;
        break;
    case 11:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group11 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 12:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group12 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
}
```

After the summary is displayed I want to send it as an email. Since there are multiple cases I need to make the switch function reusable for the email. I have tried storing it in a variable and a funcntion with value but it have not worked.

Is there any way to call this switch function for several times without copy pasting it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes! Use OOP and enjoy your life as a developer! And separate markup from the logic.

Comment: @bub That's a completely useless answer. Doesn't answer the question and just tells the OP to learn something else? Why did you feel the need to post it?

Comment: @Giedrius. You have a series of variables called `$group1` up to `$group12` that are not defined in your question. That's probably the reason its not working for you to place this code in a function.

Comment: I haven't pasted the variables, the code works fine. so I could do function switch($value){
switch.....
}
function switch($groupSplit[1]); ?

Comment: @Giedrius as long as you don't learn the very first basics you will always have the same problems. So better use OOP ;)

Comment: @bub could you be more precise what would the OOP change here ? if it is possible to store in a function why do I need OOP ?

Comment: @Giedrius. But this code needs those variables to function, so it's important to know where they're coming from? If you want to place this in a function, that function will always need access to the `$group...` variables to work.

Comment: @ben I've solved it by moving the variables into the function, the problem was that i declared function after the foreach. It works fine now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did it by myself, the problem was that function had to be declared before the foreach.

```
<?php



$answers = array();
function isEven($number){
    if ($number % 2 == 0) {
      return "No";
    } else {
        return "Yes";
    }
}


function showSummary(){
$group1 = "q1 ?";
$group2 = "q1 ?";
$group3 = "q1 ?";
$group4 = "q1 ?";
$group5 = "q1 ?";
$group6 = "q1 ?";
$group7 = "Does it archive when Archive is clicked ?";
$group8 = "q1 ?";
$group9 = "Is an Outlook archiving dialogue open ?";
$group10 = "Is Outlook still respnonding ?";
$group11 = "Does it happen all the time ?";
$group12 = "Do you get an error message ?"; 

foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {


    $groupSplit = str_split($name, 5);
//  print_r("Group Num: " . $groupSplit[1] . "<br/>");

    $optSplit = str_split($value, 3); // splits opt and the num x 
//  print_r("Option Num " . $optSplit[1] . "<br/>");



    switch ($groupSplit[1]) {
    case 1:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group1 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1] . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button><button>Confirm and Send</button>") ;
        break;
    case 2:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group2 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group3 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>" ;
        break;
    case 4:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group4 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 5:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group5 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 6:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group6 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 7:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group7 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 8:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group8 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 9:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group9 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 10:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group10 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]). "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>" ;
        break;
    case 11:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group11 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
    case 12:
        echo  "<h2>" . $group12 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
        break;
}
}






}showSummary();

showSummary();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I need more information really describe the function, but the following code is at least more concise:

```
if ($groupSplit[1] == 1){
    $retVal =  "<h2>" . $group1 . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1] . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button><button>Confirm and Send</button>") ;
}
else{
    $retVal =  "<h2>" . ${"group".$groupSplit[1]} . "</h2>" . isEven($optSplit[1]) . "<br><button onclick='window.history.back()'>Start Over</button>";
}
```